# Waiting for a forEach to finish before return from my promise / function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore, however, I think this may be more of a JavaScript asynchronous vs synchronous promise return issue.

I am doing a query to get IDs from one collection, then I am looping over the results of that query to lookup individual records from another collection based on that ID.

Then I want to store each found record into an array and then return the entire array.

`results.length` is always 0 because `return results` fires before the forEach completes. If I print `results.length` from inside the forEach it has data.

How can I wait until the forEach is done before returning from the outer promise and the outer function itself?

```
         getFacultyFavoritesFirebase() {
            var dbRef = db.collection("users").doc(global.user_id).collection("favorites");
            var dbQuery = dbRef.where("type", "==", "faculty");
            var dbPromise = dbQuery.get();
            var results = [];
            return dbPromise.then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                  var docRef = db.collection("faculty").doc(doc.id);
                  docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        results.push(doc);
                    }
                  })
                });
                console.log(results.length);
                return results;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
          }
```

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` to merge an array of promises into one promise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick here is to populate `results` with promises rather than the result. You can then call `Promise.all()` on that array of promises and get the results you want. Of course, you can't check if `doc.exists` before pushing the promise so you will need to deal with that once `Promise.all()` resolves. For example:

```
function getFacultyFavoritesFirebase() {
    var dbRef = db.collection("users").doc(global.user_id).collection("favorites");
    var dbQuery = dbRef.where("type", "==", "faculty");
    var dbPromise = dbQuery.get();
    // return the main promise
    return dbPromise.then(function(querySnapshot) {
        var results = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            var docRef = db.collection("faculty").doc(doc.id);
            // push promise from get into results
            results.push(docRef.get())
        });
        // dbPromise.then() resolves to  a single promise that resolves 
        // once all results have resolved
        return Promise.all(results)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}

getFacultyFavoritesFirebase
.then(results => {
    // use results array here and check for .exists
}
```

Comment: I saw a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594472/how-can-i-wait-for-all-promises-inside-a-loop-to-finish-before-returning-data) that used async/await - would the correct syntax in that case be: return await Promise.all(results)?

Comment: @Bruce tried this and it worked though in my case the user data is still a promise

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple items of work to perform at the same time that come from a loop, you can collect all the promises from all the items of work, and wait for them all to finish with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).  The general form of a possible solution looks like this:

```
const promises = []  // collect all promises here
items.forEach(item => {
    const promise = item.doWork()
    promises.push(promise)
})
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    // continue processing here
    // results[0] is the result of the first promise in the promises array
})
```

You can adapt this to something that suits your own specific form.

Comment: I tried many similar solutions, this is the one that worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `for of` instead of `forEach`. Like this:

```
for (const item of array) {
  //do something
}
console.log("finished");
```

"`finished`" will be logged after finishing the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know, the thread is old, but the problem is still the same. And because I did run into the same issue and non of the answers did work for me, I want share my solution.

I think it will help someone out there. And maybe it will help me, if I run into the same problem again. ;-)

So the solution is super easy. firebase implements "map" but not direct on snaposhot, but on snapshot.docs.map.
In combination with Promieses.all it works just fine.

```
const promise = snapshot.docs.map(async (tenant) => {
return CheckTenant(tenant.id).catch(error =>
    reject(error),
    );
});
Promise.all(promise).then(result => {
   // do somothing with the result});
```