# where should I place "return" in a cloud trigger

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Node.js, I am trying to create a firebase could trigger to execute when a new update applies to firebase realtime database node.
I have js code structured like this

```
    for (var player in players) {
    admin.database().ref().. {
    ..
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFCM, payload)
    }
```

I see errors for not returning promise or value. but I don't know where should I place it. Can anyone help?

Update:
Here's full code

```
for (var playerUid in players) {

         admin.database().ref('/users/' +  playerUid ).once('value', snapshot => {

          var data = snapshot.val();

          var userFCM = data["fcm"];
          console.log("userFCM: ", userFCM);

          var payload = {
              notification: {
              title: title,
                body: body
              },
              data: {
                groupId: groupId
              }
            };
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFCM, payload)
              .then(response => {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
              }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
              });

          })
    }
```

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions - it's also good to study the sample code https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/

Comment: @DougStevenson I read the docs and managed to do IOS stuff but I couldn't understand Node.js part! I am IOS developer, not node.js

Comment: Yes, you will likely have to spend some time learning a new language and environment.

Comment: I spent some time learning and I wrote the required function. and it works! but I stuck here.. I don't need you to tell me what I suppose to do

Comment: @DougStevenson you just made the question unanswerable because of your comments and downvote! why would you do that?

Comment: I didn't downvote. FYI, misunderstandings about how promises work is the #1 support issue that Cloud Functions for Firebase faces today.  We see these types of questions all the time.  Really, the way to solve these problems for everyone is to encourage folks to take time to learn how the system works, and apply the patterns that are set up in the sample code provided by the engineering team.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for a forEach to finish before return from my promise / function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743082/waiting-for-a-foreach-to-finish-before-return-from-my-promise-function)

Comment: @DougStevenson I just spent around 2 hours trying to solve it depending on the attached link and I couldn't. I asked a Node.js developer who is a youtuber announced new "node.js course" and he said "I don't exactly understand nodejs that well" on public. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7iua482mw4wtfr/Screenshot%202017-12-13%2021.03.19.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you follow the link to the issue that I think is pretty much a duplicate of what you just asked here?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, he's using the new firestore, I am using the realtime DB. maybe that's why it didn't work for me. I don't know.. but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: The pattern for the solution is exactly the same. Collect all your promises into an array and use Promise.all() to create a new promise that resolves only when all the other promises are resolved.  Return that new promise.

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFCM, payload);
```

and if this doesn't work, I would ask you to put more details in the question. So that I can check the issue thoroughly.

Comment: I believe this would stop the execution of for loop, am i wrong?

Comment: of course you are right. it will stop the loop and prevent it to occur again.

Comment: so how I suppose to return a value for firebase while I am doing all work inside the loop?

Comment: I just updated the question to include full loop code