# Use array of Promises after ForEach loop Firebase Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to push users into my array that have a number same to the one I generated. After the loop is finished I need to take the results of the loop, such as the array length, and the items that are in the array and do various things to the users in the array like credit their accounts.

I am fairly sure the best way to do this is with promises, using Promises.all to return my given array. When trying to implement this however I have run into a variety of problems, and am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to implement this. There doesn't seem to be good documentation within the docs on how to tackle the problem, so I am going through code snippets I have found on this site to help me understand how to solve this issue.

[Multiple Firestore queries, single promise / callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552876/multiple-firestore-queries-single-promise-callback)

[Waiting for a forEach to finish before return from my promise / function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743082/waiting-for-a-foreach-to-finish-before-return-from-my-promise-function)

Have been my two main references.

This is my attempt when using promises. It is not erroring out, but it does not seem to realize that the array has a length greater than 1, when the length of the array is greater than 1.

```
export const prize1 = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context: any) => {

    function getUsers() {
        let ranNum2 = '';
        for (let _i = 0; _i < 2; _i++)
            ranNum2 += String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0);

        let winnersP2: string[] = [];

        const usersRef = db.collection('users');
        let dbPromises: string[] = [];

        let _allUsers = usersRef.get().then((userSnapshot: any) => {
                userSnapshot.forEach((userDoc: any) => {
                    userDoc.ref.collection('numbers').get().then((numSnapshot: any) => {
                        numSnapshot.forEach((numDoc: any) => {


                            let pp = Number(numDoc.data().numbers);

                            if (pp == Number(ranNum2))
                                winnersP2.push(userDoc.ref.id);

                        });

                        return Promise.all(dbPromises).then(results => {
                            if (dbPromises.length > 0)
                                console.log("GREATER THAN 0");
                                //do my stuff
                            if (results.length > 0)
                                console.log("GREATER THAN 0");
                                //do my stuff

                        })

                    });
                });
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
            });

    }

    return null;

});
```

This is the base code I am trying to modify.

```
export const prize1 = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context: any) => {
        let ranNum2 = '';

        for (let _i = 0; _i < 2; _i++)
            ranNum2 += String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0);

        let winnersP2: string[] = [];

        const usersRef = db.collection('users');
        let _allUsers = usersRef.get().then((userSnapshot: any) => {
            userSnapshot.forEach((userDoc: any) => {
                userDoc.ref.collection('numbers').get().then((numSnapshot: any) => {
                    numSnapshot.forEach((numDoc: any) => {

                        let pp = Number(numDoc.data().numbers);

                        if (pp == Number(ranNum2))
                            winnersP2.push(userDoc.ref.id);

                    });
                    if (winnersP2.length > 0)
                    //do my stuff
                });
            });

        });

    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
    });

return null;
});
```

I have also tried using setTimeOut to wait until after the for loop is done, than see if the array is larger than 0, but that again didnt seem to work. That could be because my knowledge of asynchronous functions isn't correct though.

Comment: Unfortunately, product documentation isn't going to be able to address every possible situation that could come up in dealing with promises.  What I'm seeing though is that you never return a promise that resolves when all other async work is complete in the function.  That's the only thing that Cloud Functions requires.  You might want to refer to these video tutorials to help understand that better.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Doug! Trust me, I don't expect product documentation to cover every possible scenario. I have watched your videos, it is where I learned about promise.all in the first place. I will review them again and see if I can understand where I am making my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

With promises, it's important to keep the `then` and `catch` blocks lined up. Creating nested blocks can cause confusion. You also need to make sure to return a result from each block that will be dealt with in a following block.

You are trying to basically read from the `numbers` document of each user record, and deal with the resulting list of numbers. This would look something like the following:

```
userCollection.get().then((docs) => {
  return Promise.all(docs.map((docRef) => {
    return docRef.collection('numbers').get();
  });
}).then((numbersDocs) => {
  // do something with the list of docs
});
```