# I'm getting an empty array when running on firebase function but an array with values when running on react native expo on phone

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have this code below that I uploaded as a firebase function. whenever I checked the logs using **firebase functions:log**, I can see that the expoTokens array is empty.

```
var expoTokens = [];

db.collection('members').get()
.then(docs => {

   var data = []

   docs.forEach(doc => {
      if (recipients.includes(doc.id)) {
         doc.data().expoTokens.forEach(token => {
            if (!data.includes(token)) data.push(token);
         })
      }
   })

   return Promise.all(data);
})
.then((data) => {
   expoTokens = data;
})

console.log("expoTokens");
console.log(expoTokens);
```

**What I only need is to get an array of ExpoTokens so I can send notification.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log(expoTokens);` happens before `expoTokens = data;` ever runs.

See:

- [Unable to add Google markers inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60691965/unable-to-add-google-markers-inside-a-loop/60694259#60694259)
- [NodeJS, Firestore get field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684796/nodejs-firestore-get-field/52684969#52684969)
- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)
- [Waiting for a forEach to finish before return from my promise / function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743082/waiting-for-a-foreach-to-finish-before-return-from-my-promise-function)

If you want to return the expo tokens out of the Cloud Function, return them from inside `then` upwards and out of the main function:

```
return db.collection('members').get().then(docs => {
   var data = []

   docs.forEach(doc => {
      if (recipients.includes(doc.id)) {
         doc.data().expoTokens.forEach(token => {
            if (!data.includes(token)) data.push(token);
         })
      }
   })

   return Promise.all(data);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `asyc/await` to make the code flow more clear. Your functions could be written like this:

```js
var expoTokens = [];

const docs = await db.collection("members").get();

var data = [];

docs.forEach((doc) => {
  if (recipients.includes(doc.id)) {
    doc.data().expoTokens.forEach((token) => {
      if (!data.includes(token)) expoTokens.push(token);
    });
  }
});

console.log("expoTokens");
console.log(expoTokens);

// TO DO
// Send notifications using expoTokens using await

// We return to let the cloud function know that we are done
return;
```

Just don't forget the `async` in your function like `async (snap, context) => {}`